# Integrate mogenerator within Xcode 4

Tags: core-data, xcode4, mogenerator

In my application I'm using Core Data stuff to enable persistent data saving. Since I've seen that mogenerator provides a good approach to create and maintain `NSManagedObject` subclasses (also with  additional functionalities), I'm looking for some tips for integrating monogenerator within Xcode 4?

P.S. The question has been submitted based on [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Xcode 4.5+, the easiest way is to setup a "Pre-action" in your scheme:

1. Edit the scheme you want to build
2. Open the "Build" item and select "Pre-actions"
3. Click on the "+" and add a "New Run Script Action"
4. In the "Provide build settings from" popup, use the target
5. Paste this in the text area:

   ```
   # Update the mogenerator files  
   cd ${SOURCE_ROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}  
   /usr/bin/mogenerator --template-var arc=true -m ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcdatamodeld -M CoreData/Machine -H CoreData/Human`
   ```
6. Hit "OK" and build

A directory named "CoreData" will be created in your source file area along with the subdirectories "Human" and "Machine". You should now add the "CoreData" folder to your project.

Comment: My correct mark goes to you since it's receiving more upvotes. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Using mogenerator within Xcode 4 is quite simple.

First of all, download it at [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/).

Once done, switch to your Xcode project and, within the Project navigator, select your project (e.g. ProjectName).
Select *ProjectName* under **TARGETS** section.
Hold *Add Build Phase*. A menu appears. Select *Add Run Script*. A new run script will appear.
Within the text area (under shell field), add some text like the following.

> cd ProjectName mogenerator --template-var arc=true --model DataModel.xcdatamodeld/DataModel.xcdatamodel

Et voilà. When you build the project you should be able to see generated classes.

For other info and options you should refer to [mogenerator wiki](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/wiki).

Hope it helps.

P.S. Feel free to comment or modify the answer if something is wrong.

Comment: Pro Tip: Put any "Run Script" build phase scripts in an external file in the project file directory then put "./BuildScripts/run_mogenerator.sh " in Xcode. This way it is easier to track changes to the script without getting lost in the other project commits.