# Is it possible to use scalar and object properties in single NSmanagedObejct class?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

The problem is I need to use properties in NSManagedObject as scalar properties except single one NSDate property.

Can I do this without subclassing? can I just replace

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval birthDate;
```

with

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * birthDate;` ?

Or maybe there is another way to achieve this? Actually I just need one more additional state for my date property to check if `nil` (if some date actually set). Can I check it somehow with `NSTimeInterval`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just replace the Xcode generated property declaration. The actual
accessor methods are created at runtime and (magically) do the right thing.
One problem is of course that Xcode will overwrite the declaration if you re-create
the class files.

If you use "mogenerator" then you will get accessors for both the scalar `NSTimeInterval`
and the `NSDate`, as nicely explained here: [What features does mogenerator provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566121/what-features-does-mogenerator-provide).

Alternatively, you could define a "default value" in the Core Data model inspector which
is unlikely to be a real birth date.