# NSSortdescriptor without keys and use Custom Data model attribute instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

Take the following code, I have to remember what the `key` names are for my custom data models.

```
// define a sort descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"timeStamp"; ascending:YES];
NSArray *scArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
```

Is there no way that I can do something like, `myCustomDataModel.timeStamp` instead, like I do when I insert an entity into my store with my custom `managedObjects`? One reason to do it like this is reduce typing errors. (I forgot what the word is called, something along the line of type face? The word I was going for had the meaning of there being less errors due to compile time checking)

Comment: Is your question about Core Data entities? Then it might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473897/core-data-nspredicate-issue-using-constant-literals-as-names-of-properties

Comment: As Mathias' answer to @MartinR's referenced question points out, you could use `mogenerator` to do what you're looking for.  Most of the answers are pretty clumsy, but using `mogenerator` makes it pretty straight-forward.  IMO, you should always use it whenever you're using CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like that using the function NSStringFromSelector. As long as your array is filled with objects from your myCustomDataModel class, and that class has a property called timeStamp, you can do this,

```
    NSString *sortString = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(timeStamp));
    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:sortString ascending:YES];
    self.myArray = [self.myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

If you misspell the name of the selector, you will get a "undeclared selector" warning from the compiler.