# Mogenerator and Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I just installed mogenerator+xmo'd on my development machine and would like to start playing with it.  The only instructions I could really find online were from [a previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563145/how-do-i-use-mogenerator), and those don't work with XCode 4 (or at least ⌘I doesn't pull up metadata any more and I don't know how).

So to get things up and running, is all that needs to happen to add `xmod` in the .xcdatamodeld's comments (wherever they are) and the classes will be generated/updated on save from then on?

Comment: Xcode 4's still subject to an NDA, so you shouldn't/won't be able to get an answer here.

Comment: Try the Apple Developer forums. You can discuss NDA material there.

Comment: You can use the command line to solve this issue,  if you're still interested in the answer, i'll post a response that will solve the issus for you

Answer (score 7):

While trying to find this answer myself, I found [MOGenerator and Xcode 4 integration guide](http://www.esenciadev.com/2011/05/mogen-and-xcode4-integration/) on esenciadev.com. This solution is not a push-button integration, but it works. The link has detailed instructions, but generally you:

1. Copy the shell scripts into your project
2. Add build rules to your target to run the two shell scripts

When you build your project, the script runs MOGenerator on all .xcdatamodel files in your project directory. After the build, if the script generates *new* class files, you must manually add them to your project. Subsequent builds will remember existing MO-Generated files.

Caveats:

1. The example's build rule assumes you put the scripts into a /scripts/ file folder within your project directory. When I ignored this detail (creating a *project* folder but not a *file* folder) I got a build error. Make sure the build rule points to the script's file location.
2. The script uses the `--base-class` argument. Unless your model classes are subclasses of a custom class (not NSManagedObject), you must delete this argument from the script. E.g.,

```
mogenerator --model "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}/$curVer" --output-dir "${INPUT_FILE_DIR}/" --base-class $baseClass
```

Comment: The tutorial provided seems to include some unnecessary steps. Does anyone know why mogen.sh and mogend.sh are both needed? Wouldn't running a custom script that simply calls mogenerator on the current version of hhe datamodel be adequate?

Comment: I think so. I was unfamiliar with mogenerator when I posted. After reading your comment, I tried using the mogend.sh script and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Now that Xcode 4 is released Take a look at the [Issues](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/issues#issue/48) page for mogenerator

Answer (score 4):

After I make changes to my model file, I just run mogenerator manually from the terminal.  Using Xcode 4 and ARC, this does the trick:

```
cd <directory of model file>
mogenerator --model <your model>.xcdatamodeld/<current version>.xcdatamodel --template-var arc=YES
```

Maybe I'll use build scripts at some point, but the terminal approach is too simple to screw up.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Script in the "Build Phases" to be more reliable than the "Build Rules".

Under "Build Phases" for your Target, choose the button at the bottom to "Add Run Script". Drag the run script to the top so that it executes before compiling sources.

Remember that the actual data model files (.xcdatamodel) are contained within a package (.xcdatamodeld), and that you only need to compile the latest data model for your project.

Add the following to the script (replacing text in angle-brackets as appropriate)

```
MODELS_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/<path to your models without trailing slash>"
DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE="$MODELS_DIR/<your model name>.xcdatamodeld"
CURRENT_VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE/.xccurrentversion" -c 'print _XCCurrentVersionName'`

# Mogenerator Location
if [ -x /usr/local/bin/mogenerator ]; then
    echo "mogenerator exists in /usr/local/bin path";
    MOGENERATOR_DIR="/usr/local/bin";
elif [ -x /usr/bin/mogenerator ]; then
    echo "mogenerator exists in /usr/bin path";
    MOGENERATOR_DIR="/usr/bin";
else
    echo "mogenerator not found"; exit 1;
fi

$MOGENERATOR_DIR/mogenerator --model "$DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE/$CURRENT_VERSION" --output-dir "$MODELS_DIR/"
```

Add options to `mogenerator` as appropriate. `--base-class <your base class>` and  `--template-var arc=true` are common.

Answer (score 0):

Random tip.  If you get Illegal Instruction: 4 when you run mogenerator.  Install it from the command line:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade mogenerator
```