# pathForResource:ofType: returns 'nil' if a build rule for 'Data model version files' is used

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to setup CoreData in a new project, but somehow am stuck locating the momd directory.

I found several stackoverflow posts with similar questions, but was unable to solve the problem with the supplied answers. So here it is: What causes the first line to return 'nil' and the second one actually finds the momd directory?

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Project" ofType:@"momd"]
];

NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
    @"/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-afusjhpzsjyjdbesttxposfzlzrj/Build/Products/Debug/Project.app/Contents/MacOS/Project.momd"
];
```

Edit: As Metabble commented, It's now logical that the mainbundle is unable to locate resources outside the Resources folder.

But my problem still exists. I found out some more:
I am using mogenerator to generate classes. (I used these instructions: http://www.esenciadev.com/2011/05/mogen-and-xcode4-integration/).
A script is called by a build rule process 'Data model version files'. In that build rule I've set the output to '${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.momd' but it looks like that is not the correct destination for the momd:

```
error: Could not create bundle folder for versioned model at '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-afusjhpzsjyjdbesttxposfzlzrj/Build/Products/Debug/Project.app/Contents/MacOS/Project.momd'
```

If I delete the build rule, the code can find the momd.
But that disables mogenerator...

Anybody know what output files I need to set in the build rule?

Comment: What do you see if you use `NSLog(@"Path: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Project" ofType:@"momd"]);`?

Comment: That also returns nil: 
"Path: (null)"

Comment: OK, how about `NSLog(@"Path: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);`?  (I suspect it's looking in a "Resources" sub-folder, but I'd rather have it tell you than guess.)

Comment: Yep, the Resources folder:
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-afusjhpzsjyjdbesttxposfzlzrj/Build/Products/Debug/Project.app/Contents/Resources

Comment: So, this is solved then? The file you want resides in a subdirectory other than `Resources` but `pathForResource:ofType:` only checks the `Resources` subdirectory followed by the top level localization subdirectories, right?

Comment: Not solved yet.. It looks like the problem is because of a build rule I have. I need to edit the question a bit.

Comment: You might as well use `URLForResource:withExtension:`, which will create the URL for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add a build rule to your project that copies the Project.momd file to your app's Resource directory.

Comment: You mean the '${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.momd' part of my build rule? I'm not sure why that resolves to a dir outside the App's resource directory....

Comment: I see that someone voted this up. Do you have any idea how to accomplish copying the momd dir to the resource directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Found my workaround in [Mogenerator and Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118718/mogenerator-and-xcode-4)

I removed the build rules and am now using a Run Script phase instead:

```
MODELS_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Resources/Main/CoreData"
DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE="$MODELS_DIR/Project.xcdatamodeld"
CURRENT_VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE/.xccurrentversion" -c 'print _XCCurrentVersionName'`

mogenerator --template-var arc=true --model "$DATA_MODEL_PACKAGE/$CURRENT_VERSION" --output-dir "$MODELS_DIR/Sources/Main/Classes"
```

This works just fine. It is weird though about the build rules. I use those in a different project without any problems...

Thanks Phillip & Metabble !!